# android , i got error Unfortunately Stopped

Tags: android

i got an error on this ,, Unfortunately Stopped

```
package com.example.myapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */

    public int myNum = 0;
    public TextView counterNum = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.counterNum);
    public Button counterBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.counterBtn);

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        counterBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                counterNum.setText(String.valueOf(++myNum));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

please help me to tell me why i got stopped .

and here the main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="0"
        android:id="@+id/counterNum"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="68dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:textSize="100dp"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:numeric="integer"/>

<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="+"
        android:id="@+id/counterBtn"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="147dp"
        android:textSize="45dp"
        android:textColor="#ff0a000a"
        android:width="100dp"
        android:height="100dp"/>
```

my logcat

> 12-03 12:19:37.718    1063-1063/com.example.myapp E/Trace﹕ error
>   opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
>       12-03 12:19:38.348    1063-1063/com.example.myapp D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
>       12-03 12:19:38.359    1063-1063/com.example.myapp D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x2a0dbe58, tid
>   1063
>       12-03 12:19:38.399    1063-1063/com.example.myapp D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
>       12-03 12:19:38.409    1063-1063/com.example.myapp D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
>       12-03 12:19:38.588    1063-1063/com.example.myapp W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
>       12-03 12:19:38.609    1063-1063/com.example.myapp D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0

i am using IntellIJ Idea

Comment: it got "stopped" because there is an error, post the error

Comment: add your stack trace

Comment: Where's your logcat?

Comment: i am useing intellIJ IDEA editor

Answer (score 0):

**The character '+' can't be set as text on the xml itself.**

Set '+' as text in /values/strings.xml file as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="plus_sign">+</string>
</resources>
```

XML Layout file:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/plus_sign" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In your string.xml file, you set a string with special character which is not allowed.
Try to add "\" before "+". See below:

```
<resources>
    <string name="plus_sign">\+</string>
</resources>
```

Or you can encode it with &#43;
See the code below:

```
<resources>
    <string name="plus_sign">&#43</string>
</resources>
```

You can find encodes here: [link](http://www.degraeve.com/reference/specialcharacters.php)